# Javascript / Typescript - Compare letters from two string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript

what is the most efficient way to compare letters from two strings f.e

`let str1 = "master";`
`let str2 = "programmer";`

and now as you see those strings are different but i want to check how many letters they have in common and how many sequences they have (sequence is when there are more than 2 letters in sequence in common). In this example we have:
lettersIncommon = 4 (m,a,e,r)
lettersInSequence = 2 (er)

Comment: _"what is the most efficient way"_ What are the benchmarks for the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry?

Comment: This is a two part question. For the second part I recommend [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) as the problem is very well known and extensively studied.